# Estimate variance of a long-run coefficient in the ECM framework

Tags: regression, variance, ardl

Consider the following unrestricted linear ECM:

$$\Delta y_t=\mu+\beta_1 y_{t-1}+ \beta_2 x_{t-1} + \gamma \Delta x_t +\epsilon_t.$$

Now, suppose we have the estimated coefficients ($\widehat{\mu}, \widehat{\beta}_1, \widehat{\beta}_2, \widehat{\gamma}$) and their variances. The long-run coefficient for $x_t$ is defined as:

$$L_x=\frac{\beta_2}{-\beta_1}.$$

The question is: having the estimated $\widehat{\beta}_1$ and $\widehat{\beta}_2$ and their variances, i.e., $\text{Var}(\widehat{\beta}_1)$ and $\text{Var}(\widehat{\beta}_2)$, how manually estimate $\text{Var}(\widehat{L}_x)$ and find its corresponding $t$-stat/$p$-value? Thanks in advance!